# #pragma omp parallel never ending

Tags: c++, openmp

My code is below, for some reason my program never seems to exit the `parallel` region.

My code gets to the

```
cout<< omp_get_thread_num()<<" done"<< endl;
```

line, but it is only ever executed by the root (0) process, and it never gets to the

```
cout<<"done2?"<< endl;
```

part.

It's like it has entered an infinite loop or something. It doesn't even make sense to me that each thread doesn't `cout` that it is done as I added the `omp barrier` before it so every thread would have had to reach it before the root could even say it is done. Your help is appreciated.

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(desiredNumThreads)
{
    double startTime;
    #pragma omp master
    {
        startTime = omp_get_wtime();
    }           
    while (!Converged)
    {
        #pragma omp master
        {
            iteration++;
        }
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixsize; i++)
        {
            oldX[i] = newX[i];
            //newX[i] = Bmatrix[i];
        }
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixsize; i++)
        {
            newX[i] = Bmatrix[i]; //new part
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixsize; j++)
            {
                if (j != i)
                {
                    newX[i] = newX[i] - matrix[i][j] * oldX[j];
                }
            }
            newX[i] = newX[i] / matrix[i][i]; //new part
        }
        #pragma omp master
        {
            Converged = true;
        }
        #pragma omp barrier 
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i<matrixsize; i++)
        {
            if (abs(oldX[i] - newX[i]) > Tolerance)
            {
                Converged = false;
            }
        }   
    }
    #pragma omp master
    {
        double endTime = omp_get_wtime();
        cout << "This took " << iteration << " iterations. " << endl;
        cout << "This took " << endTime - startTime << " seconds" << endl;
        cout << "File to Print answer to? ";
        cin >> filename;
        ofstream fout(filename);
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixsize; i++)
        {
            fout << fixed << newX[i] << endl;
        }                   
    }
    #pragma omp barrier 
    cout<<omp_get_thread_num()<<" done"<<endl;  
}
cout<<"done2?"<<endl;
```

Comment: Did you try the same code, but without OMP? Debugging OMP code is a lot harder. Make sure that the underlying code gives the correct results first.

Comment: Yes the code works in sequential and the output is correct in parallel as well, it just never exits the code block after finishing though

Comment: Some more suggestions: 1) What happens when `desiredNumThreads` is 1? 2) Add `cout << "Thread" << omp_get_thread_num()<<" started"<<endl;` to the beginning of the block. What compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: It correctly terminates when I only use 1 thread, and prints out all the threads (32 is what I used) when I add that to the beginning of the code block. I am using VS2012 Windows 8.1

Comment: While testing I noticed something even weirder, if I run in debug mode it correctly terminates (I had been running in release mode the whole time). Still doesn't finish in release though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed it by moving the last section

```html
#pragma omp master
    {
        double endTime = omp_get_wtime();
        cout << "This took " << iteration << " iterations. " << endl;
        cout << "This took " << endTime - startTime << " seconds" << endl;
        cout << "File to Print answer to? ";
        cin >> filename;
        ofstream fout(filename);
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixsize; i++)
        {
            fout << fixed << newX[i] << endl;
        }                   
    }
```

out of the parallel section and doing it in sequential (since it was already sequential anyway).
Why this fixed the problem I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcc2ey75.aspx), the maximum number of threads is 10. Change `desiredNumThreads` to 10 or less and it should work.

Comment: I tried with 2, 10 and 5 and it still doesn't terminate. :/ And interestingly enough when I was saying 32 earlier it still printed out 0-31 (zero indexed) when I added the test cout << "Thread" << omp_get_thread_num()<<" started"<<endl; part.

Comment: @Spamus Do the processors appear busy as in a loop, or are they waiting? Also, you mean that when you specify a specific number of threads, it still launches 32?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, the code works in Debug configuration but not in Release configuration.  This indicates to me that the compiler is making optimizations that prevent the code functioning.  These optimizations likely come from the OpenMP memory model I would suggest to read about the OpenMP memory model).  There are several flaws in the original code (race conditions in the statement ("Converged = true").  Adding proper synchronization will forces the compiler to correctly update the variable Converged and will likely make the problem go away.

Cheers,
        -michael

Comment: Depending on how `Converged` is declared, this is likely to be the answer. I assumed it was shared, but it might not be. Fuller details regarding whether `Converged` is shared or private can be found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/proguide/cuppvars.htm) (assuming the compilers behave similarly, which might not be a safe assumption).